# How do I get an access token from the Facebook signed request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0

We are using the Facebook Javascript SDK to authenticate our users.

Once a user authenticates, the user gets a fbsr_<app_id> cookie containing a signed request.

We then use AJAX to post some information to our server.  The server receives the cookie with the signed request, but when the server parses the signed request (modified python SDK) in the cookie, it decodes the JSON object as:

```
{
   "algorithm": "HMAC-SHA256",
   "code": "2.AQDBJ3-ZpURb9P4T.3600.1316037600.1-786359552|BNK6FGOAkvMs7slboQMSIEJYDWc",
   "issued_at": 1316031333,
   "user_id": "786359552"
}
```

This is contrary to what the [signed request documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) says we should get.

The server needs the access token, so it can get some additional information with the GraphAPI.

How do we get the access token from the signed request?

Comment: The answer is here:
[http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7201521/problem-getting-access-token-after-migrating-to-oauth-2-0][1]


  [1]: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7201521/problem-getting-access-token-after-migrating-to-oauth-2-0

Answer (score 2):

using the new oauth2 workflow with the javascript sdk the user token will be available.

After you authenticate you can find the token with something like this

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

              if (response.status === 'connected') { 

                alert(response.authResponse.accessToken);

              }
        });
```

Once you have the token you can just pass that back to your backend to query the graph.

Comment: Works flawlessly dunno why OP is asleep!

Comment: Because this answer did not address the question asked.  The answer was provided in the comment to my question.

Comment: I had the same problem with unreliable cookie-setting. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The correct one is:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

          if (response.status === 'connected') { 

            alert(response.session.access_token);

          }
    });
```